# В RStudio не загружается пакет devtools

Tags: rstudio

У меня возникла проблема с загрузкой пакета devtools в RStudio.
При вводе команды:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

Появляется следующее сообщение:

```
One or more of the packages that will be updated by this installation are currently loaded. Restarting R prior to updating these packages is strongly recommended.

RStudio can restart R and then automatically continue the installation after restarting (all work and data will be preserved during the restart)

Do you want to restart R prior to installing?
```

При нажатии "Yes" происходит перезапуск сессии RStudio и начинается загрузка пакета devtools. Но до своего завершения загрузка не доходит, и в конце снова появляется вышеописанное сообщение о необходимости перезапуска сессии Rstudio.

Прошу помочь с решением данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Тут есть несколько выходов:

1. Переустановить RStudio. Многие мои коллеги, которые кодят и делают аналитику в R, сталкивались с этой проблемой. Она, хоть и не часто, но исчезает после переустановки интегрированной среды разработки.
2. Возможно, `devtools` уже загружена. Чтобы это проверить, в консоли можно написать `.libPaths()` или `find.package`. Эти команды позволят тебе увидеть, есть ли папки с библиотеками в памяти. Если они есть, удали их. Потом снова попробуй установить `install.package()`.